# How to convert SDL_renderer to SDL_window?

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

I'm starting with SDL2 and and having some trouble trying to conver SDL_renderer to SDL_window.
How I can convert SDL_rnderer to SDL_window exactly?

Comment: Why do you think this is something that you would be able to do, and why would you want to do it?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot, they are different structures.

Anyway, you can create a `SDL_Renderer` for a given `SDL_Window` by means either of the [SDL_CreateRenderer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateRenderer) method or the [SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindowAndRenderer?highlight=%28%5CbCategoryRender%5Cb%29%7C%28CategoryEnum%29%7C%28CategoryStruct%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible.
A window is, well, a window.
While a renderer is responsible for rendering/generating the image.
The "insides" of a window usually consists of a renderer.

In this way, a window uses a renderer which should explain why it's not possible to convert a renderer to a window.